# Handle file chooser android WebViews

Tags: android, webview

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mitrOm.jpg)

I have an issue guys. I have a `webView` app. Inside the app is a button that should enable user pick file from device and upload to api. Everything was handled with the web. The problem is that on the `webView` app, on tapping the button, nothing happens, however, when I try with a chrome browser or a browser app, it works well.

What do I need to do to ensure it works the same way as the chrome browser?  I don't want to handle this functionality natively as that's the only solutions I saw online. I tried doing that anyways, but it doesn't pop out those file options like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPELK.jpg)

Is there an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
private var filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?): Boolean {
                startActivityForResult(fileChooserParams?.createIntent(), CHOOSE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
                this@MainActivity.filePathCallback = filePathCallback
                return true
            }
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            CHOOSE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    filePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data))
                    filePathCallback = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a way I could make the options show up like the way it does on a web browser?

Comment: this requires me to handle the file intent natively on the app which is painstaking. On the web, we have already handled everything including the api. And it works well on chrome browser on mobile. Is there not a way I could make it behave the same way with WebViews without handling it manually?

Comment: this doesn't show other options like camera?
If you open the HTML page in a web browser, then is it showing the camera option.
You can not open the camera directly from the web view. To open the camera, you have to write some native code because you are communicating with the hardware layer of android. So i think, without writing the code in native you can not access it from webview.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the webview like,

```
    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     
    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

and need to set up custom `WebViewClient, check out the link for more details.
[Open file chooser in webview](https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148).

Let me know if it is working for you or not.

Comment: this requires me to handle the file intent natively on the app which is painstaking. On the web, we have already handled everything including the api. And it works well on chrome browser on mobile. Is there not a way I could make it behave the same way with WebViews without handling it manually?